# Javascript/Jquery How to format each item in array

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im importing an txt file into an array using jquery like so:

```
var testarray= new Array();
    $.get('locationtosavedfile', function(data){
            testarray= new Date(data.split('\n'));
            console.log(testarray);
        });
```

The contents of the file look like so:

```
"October 12, 2013 06:06:00"
"October 12, 2013 06:36:00"
"October 12, 2013 07:19:00"
"October 12, 2013 07:24:00"
"October 12, 2013 07:39:00"
"October 12, 2013 07:54:00"
"October 12, 2013 08:06:00"
"October 12, 2013 08:46:00"
"October 12, 2013 09:06:00"
```

The file is loaded into the array fine though its not making a date due to an formatting issue but im sure it should be okay? the text its importing is the same format as

```
new Date("October 12, 2013 10:12:00");
```

Which when added manually does work.

The error im getting is: Invalid Date. If I output the array the results are all there and separated by a comma.If there is something i'm missing let me know..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to pass an array of such strings to `new Date`, not doing them one at a time.

Use [ES5 `.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to convert an array from one format to another:

```
testarray = data.split('\n').map(function(v) {
    return new Date(v);
});
```

Comment: var testarray = new Array();
     $.get('myfilehere.txt', function(data) {}
       testarray = data.split('\n').map(function(v)) {
                 return new Date(v);
 
  });                                                                             this still does not work for me I have tried a few variations always errors how can I fix/

Comment: @MarkCowley define "doesn't work".  As it stands, you do know you can't use `testarray` until _after_ the `$.get` call is completely finished, don't you?  You need to start up anything else that depends on `testarray` inside the callback.

Comment: Yes I know that. Try compile it it wont work. Just formatting issues left right center

Comment: Okay I got it to work by changing the curly brackets around although it seems not to assign each item an [i] how to fix?

Comment: @MarkCowley you're not giving us much to go on - when I test the above code it works, although you do have to ensure that there's no `\n` on the final line of `data`, otherwise the `.split` will create an empty element on the end of the list.

Comment: There is definitely not an blank line at the end. Im getting error "Invalid Date"

Comment: I didn't say a blank line, I said a trailing `\n`.  I'm off to bed shortly - if you need more help, produce a _small self contained example_ (perhaps on jsfiddle.net).  I can't debug your problem with so little information.

Comment: @MarkCowley yes, the `null` you're getting is _exactly_ what I warned you about above re: the `$.get` call.  Lookup any of the _numerous_ questions on here about accessing the results of AJAX calls.  See http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/aBc7s/1/

Comment: Hi there, Getting this error now: Uncaught TypeError: Object Invalid Date has no method 'map'

Comment: @MarkCowley did you look at my fiddle, and the comments therein?

Comment: does not work at all for me. Have tried exact copy of your code. have you actually tried it? you will get invalid date same as mine:  10-15 16:51:14.623: E/Web Console(531): Uncaught TypeError: Object Invalid Date has no method 'map' at file:///android_asset/www/index.html:153

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/aBc7s/2/ tried that as well no luck either. Should my text file have quotes? tried without no success either.